# hacer un método de suma de racionales

Tags: java

Me pidieron hacer un método de suma de racionales, el profe nos dio los atributos y la forma de impresión, pero como podría hacer el método suma, nos pidió que no creáramos más métodos. Si alguien me podría asesorar un poco respecto al método que hice o no tengo idea de lo que estoy haciendo? De antemano gracias!

```
public class Racionales1{ 
    int numerador
    int denominador

   
    public static Racionales1 suma(Racionales1 a, Racionales1 b) {
        Racionales1 r3 = new Racionales1()
        r3.numerador = ((a.numerador*b.denominador)+(a.denominador*b.numerador))
        r3.denominador=a.denominador*b.denominador
        return r3
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Racionales1 r1=new Racionales1()
        Racionales1 r2=new Racionales1()
        Racionales1 r3=new Racionales1()
        r1.numerador=1
        r1.denominador=2
        r2.numerador=3
        r2.denominador=4
        r3=suma(r1,r2)
        System.out.println("El reultados es: " + r3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues de momento lo que puedes hacer es poner el código como texto. Mira que tengo una pantalla grande, pero ni con un microscopio leo esa imagen. Luego edita también el título, los títulos de las preguntas deben ser una breve descripción del problema, para que la gente pueda decidir si va a intentar dedicar su tiempo a responder una pregunta, debe saber qué se pregunta! Te recomiendo leer [ask], hacer el [tour] y si te quedas con dudas, en [help] hay muchísima información sobre cómo funciona StackOverflow, cómo elaborar preguntas correctamente y todo lo que necesites.

Comment: De hecho intente poner el código pero no me dejó ponerlo

Comment: Dale a editar y pega ahi tu codigo como texto

Comment: Vale, ahora que la pregunta ya me permite leer el código... cual es el error? Has dicho que tenías que hacer un método para sumar racionales... y yo veo un método para sumar racionales hecho. Qué ***problema*** tienes?

Comment: Ver si esta correcto el método y otra en caso que este correcto como hacerlo para que realice la suma y me imprima el resultado

Comment: Los has hecho bien, cual es el problema

Comment: No me imprime el resultado. :( me aparece esto. -"Practica1.Racionales1@4617c264"

Comment: Sin tocar la parte matemática, a la hora de imprimir un objeto no puedes simplemente hacer `System.out.println(objetoAqui);` puesto que lo que imprimirá es la *referencia* de dicho objeto. Para solucionar esto, puedes hacer dos cosas, A) Cada vez que imprimas, formatearlo a tu gusto -> `System.out.println("Racional sumado: " + r3.numerador + " / " + r3.denominador);` o sobreescribir el método `toString()` en tu clase Racionales1. Cuando imprimes un objeto, java hace una llamada al método `toString()` del objeto, que si no está sobreescrito lo que hace es devolver la referencia del mismo :)

Comment: No te los imprime porque deberias o bien hacer un metodo imprimirFraccion, y ademas hacer unas propiedades publicas en la clase getNumerador() y getDenominador que te te devuelvan el numerador y el denominador

Comment: Para sobreescribir el método toString basta con declarar el método: `@Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Racional: " + this.numerador + " / " + this.denominador";
  }`. El @Override se emplea para indicar que estás sobreescribiendo un método que ya existe, así java llamará a tu método cuando intentes imprimir el objeto :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Benito, justamente la primera opción me sirvió para que me diera y a Japv muchísimas, ya que la siguiente parte de esta tarea me pide lo que me comentaste

Comment: Recomendaciones: #1 Usa un constructor con parámetros para asignar los valores, y *setters* y *getters* (`setNumerador(int numerador)`, `getDenominador()`) para acceder a los valores. #2 Pon el método main en una clase diferente, de forma que tu clase `Racionales1` no tenga un método `main`. #3 Cambia el nombre a `Racional` (cada instancia de `Racional` representa un único número).